# How to change the shape of UIImageviewr in xcode

Tags: ios7, uiimageview

I need to change the UIImageviewr shape to rounded edges, if there is a way I can change this without modifying the code that would be easiest. If your solution is in the code please tell me where I need to put it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the code in the view controller that owns the image view.
But first, for that you're going to need the `QuartzCore` framework.
Add that framework to your project in the `Build Phases` - `Link Binary With Libraries` from your target settings.
After importing `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in the view controller, you need to actually *round* those edges by accessing a property called `cornerRadius` on the `UIImageView`'s layer. To do that:

```
_myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
```

That line of code could go in the `viewDidLoad` method if you want the image to have rounded corners when the view appears. (Or elsewhere if you need something specific)

Good luck!